# Junit Test doesn't seems to call the tested method

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, intellij-14

i have a method, say

```
@PostMapping(value = "/vpos/notify", ...)
public Foo somethingJSON(Bar bar) throws Exception { ... }
```

and i have a test unit into another class which goes like this

```
@Test
public void shouldInvokesomethingJson() throws Exception {   
    //given
    String jsonContent = TestDataFactory.createInputRestRequest("1.4", "VposRequest");
    //when
    mvc.perform(
        post("(path)/vpos/notify")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, token)
            .content(jsonContent)
    )
    //then
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andDo(print());
}
```

even though test came up with success, I can't really say if it goes into the method...

I tried to verify if the path was wrong, but if I insert anything else, it says it can't find the method to test.

Still i'm not sure if it goes into the method, following the Postmapping annotation, 'cause i've inserted breakpoints into the method, but when I ran "debug" the execution does not go there.

still in the log I got this:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
HTTP Method = POST
Request URI = .../vpos/notify
...
```

which is telling me it is mocking to the right URI as written in `@PostMapping`

Which is the cause of this strange behavior?

Comment: temporarily let your production code throw a `RuntimeException`. This should tell you if its being executed or not. For the future you might consider writing your test *first* so you see the test fail before, and succeed after you have added the tested behavior in your production code (TDD).

Comment: After I was about to write an answer I was asking me: can you put a breakpoint in the test itself? Does this work? Other than that: how did you configure your controller to be used? I suspect you might need to check on this. I usually try to go with a standalone test (using the controller as parameter of the "standaloneSetup()" to be sure my test env. is correct.

Comment: I don't wrote those details 'cause that part is all set and working, and yes i've put a breakpoint even in the test method, still the one in the method doesn't trigger, the one in the test does.

So, i don't know if it is REALLY testing

Answer (score 0):

XD

There was another method who call with a generic URI, that kicks in because the content type did not match with the method I want to call, but with the generic one...

Ah, the details...